# Attachment using node.js, express, email.js, and gmail

Tags: node.js, email, attachment

I am trying to send a basic attachment using email.js + gmail. I've read the documentation and even looked at the source code of email.js but still can't get it..

Basically, my code sends an email but there is no attachment. When I check the original message in gmail, it says there is an `Attachement: [object Object],[object Object]` , but nothing is there in the message to indicate anything is attached.

Here's the node.js/express code

```
var 
  fs            = require('fs')
  , path          = require('path')
  , filename      = 'helloworld.txt'
  , filepath      = path.join('./', filename)
  , email         = require('emailjs')
  , server        = email.server.connect({ 
    user: process.env.GMAIL_USER
    , password: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
    , host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    , ssl: true
  });

// POST, /mail, create
exports.create = function(req, res, model) {
  var sendEmail = function () {
    var message = {
      from: 'John <realemailhere@gmail.com>'
      , to: req.body.email
      , subject: 'Testing emailjs with an attachement'
      , text: 'Is there anything attached ?'
      , attachement: [ 
        { data: 'helloworld.txt', name: 'helloworld.txt' }
        , { path: filepath, name: filename}   ]
    };

    server.send(message, function(err, response) { res.json(err || message); });
  };

  sendEmail();
};
```

What would cause this to correctly send an email, but include have the actual email include `Attachement: [object Object],[object Object]` , causing no file attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is insanely embarrassing, but attachment is spelled `attachment`, and not as `attachement`. Note the extra `e` in my code above.

Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but you're attaching two attachments with the same exact name, helloworld.txt.  Try removing the first attachment, with the `data` attribute, since it's almost certainly not what you want.  At minimum, rename one of your attachments.

```
var 
  fs            = require('fs')
  , path          = require('path')
  , filename      = 'helloworld.txt'
  , filepath      = path.join('./', filename)
  , email         = require('emailjs')
  , server        = email.server.connect({ 
    user: process.env.GMAIL_USER
    , password: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
    , host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    , ssl: true
  });

// POST, /mail, create
exports.create = function(req, res, model) {
  var sendEmail = function () {
    var message = {
      from: 'John <realemailhere@gmail.com>'
      , to: req.body.email
      , subject: 'Testing emailjs with an attachement'
      , text: 'Is there anything attached ?'
      , attachement: [ 
        { data: 'helloworld.txt', name: 'helloworld0.txt' } // renamed this attachment
        , { path: filepath, name: filename}   ] // left this attachment alone
    };

    server.send(message, function(err, response) { res.json(err || message); });
  };

  sendEmail();
};
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response!  I'm still getting `Attachement: [object Object],[object Object]` back from gmail though... does that hint to anything that's going wrong? 

Maybe it's not scoped right (eg `attachment[0]`) or something? 

Or maybe I need to send the email in the MIME format instead?

Comment: well, I can tell you that [object Object] is the generic way node denotes an object casting to a string... which is strange.  Try adding a MIME type with `type: 'text/plain'` to your attachment, so that it matches up exactly with the examples on the README